# What's difference between request's thread and program's thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm almost new to Java. I know multithreading is the action of separating program into several tasks so that they can run concurrently. I have two problems with this concepts.

First of all, it's been said that application server creates a thread per each request. I can't associate this per-request-thread with program's threads. Suppose a program in which there are 5 threads to do things concurrently. How that single thread per request is going to deal with the 5 threads of that program?

Secondly, I have problem grasping the idea of thread pool. Is it about the threads that application server creates per request or it's regarding programs's threads that do tasks concurrently?

Comment: a) You connect to a web and ask for something. The server creates and dedicates a thread for you.
b)Thread pool. That's a way of reusing threads and optimizing performance of multithreaded jobs. This way, you don't create a thread each time, but you ask the pool if there are threads avaliable for your job. So simplistic, but hey.

Comment: A thread is a thread, whether it is serving a request, reading a file or fetching from a database. You may have 5 concurrent requests, each being served by a different thread and have 5 more threads doing something else. And a thread pool is just a pattern to avoid frequent thread creation as creating threads is expensive.

Comment: A program can create and destroy threads while it is running. A simplistic server might have one thread that waits for connection requests, and that _listener thread_ might create a new _client thread_ to handle each request. A more sophisticated listener thread would create a new _task_ object for each incoming request, and it would submit the tasks to be executed by a _[thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)._ The thread pool approach performs better because it does not waste time creating and destroying threads.

Comment: @aran
I'm still confused. A thread is dedicated for each request. I can't associate this thread with the threads of program itself.

Comment: @DanielHajjari How do you mean "associate this thread with the threads of program itself"? The thread just runs whatever it runs. Do you mean how can you let threads communicate with each other?

Comment: @xtratic
You got close to what I have in my mind. application server allocates one thread to my request. But the program for example has 5 threads that execute concurrently. How the communication of those 5 threads would be here?

Comment: For example, the thread that's been assigned to serve you sends a rest message to a server. Or it may connect to other threads through socket, ipc, shared memory...and so on. The important thing is, a thread is just a thread, it runs. Communication between threads is not  a essential thing for them, just another job. They may not communicate at all, as in parallel process jobs.

Answer (score 0):

> I have problem grasping the idea of thread pool.

A simple thread pool is a collection of running threads (a.k.a., *worker* threads) in which, each thread continually tries to take a *task* object from a `BlockingQueue`, and when it gets one, it *executes* the task, and then goes back to the queue to wait for another one.

A task is an object with some well-known method that the worker calls in order to "execute" the task. E.g., in the thread pools defined by the Java standard library, task objects either are `Runnable` instances or `Callable` instances, and the worker executes a task by calling `task.run()` or by `task.call()`.